# passportjs, tokenSecret returns an empty object

Tags: authentication, express, token, passport.js, trello

guys, I'm using passport-trello for user authentication in my App.

```
export default () => {
  passport.use(new TrelloStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TRELLO_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TRELLO_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/trello/callback',
    trelloParams: {
      scope: 'read',
      name: 'Common Feed',
      expiration: '1hour'
    }
  }, (req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
      let user = {};
      user.token = token;
      user.tokenSecret = tokenSecret;
      user.profile = profile;
      done(null, user);
  }));
}
```

When I'm trying to log out user object it turns out that `user.tokenSecret` returns an empty object, while other props is filled with corresponding info. I'm wondering if someone had this issue and why it happens to be so. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that that `req` argument is exactly that tokenSecret! Strange behaviour but it is what it is. `req` return a string, which you can use to access Trello's API. Hope it will help somebody